# How do you do joins in hibernate activerecord?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

How do I do a join that would return me results similar to-

```
SELECT * FROM Project LEFT JOIN ProjectRegion ON ProjectRegion.id = Project.projectRegion
```

I currently use the syntax-

```
  Project[] projects = Project.FindAll();
```

My tables are setup with ActiveRecord/hibernate as follows -

```
    [ActiveRecord]
    public class ProjectRegion : ActiveRecordBase<ProjectRegion>
    {
        private int id;
        private String title;

        public ProjectRegion()
        {
        }

        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        [Property]
        public String Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { title = value; }
        }
    }


    [ActiveRecord]
    public class Project : ActiveRecordBase<Project>
    {
        private int id;
        private String projectNumber;
        private String projectRegion;

        public Project()
        {
        }

        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        [Property]
        public String ProjectInternalCode
        {
            get { return projectNumber; }
            set { projectNumber = value; }
        }

        [Property]
        public String ProjectRegion
        {
            get { return projectRegion; }
            set { projectRegion = value; }
        }
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't your ProjectRegion property in the Project class be of type ProjectRegion instead of string?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but that still won't do the join will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the ProjectRegion property in the Project class to be of type ProjectRegion instead of string, when NHibernate fetches a Project it will automatically join (according to a fetch policy) the ProjectRegion table.

Comment: I did that and had to change [Property] to [BelongsTo("ProjectRegion")] and now it works.

Beautiful, thanks!